# How many numbers in $\{2,3,...,360\}$ share at least one prime factor with $360$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

What is the best way to go about solving this question?

Comment: Use that $360=2^3\cdot 3^2 \cdot 5.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

their are 180 numbers have factor 2, 120 of them have factor 3 and 72 have factor 5, 60 have factor of 2 and 3, 36 for 2 and 5, 24 for 3 and 5, 12 for 2,3 and 5.

Therefore, the total number is :
180+120+72-60-36-24+12=264

Comment: shouldn´t it be one less for each of the factors, since the number 1 isn´t included in the set?

Comment: @imc 1 doesn't share any prime factor with 360. 1 is not a prime, nor can it be decomposed using prime.

Comment: It may be useful to point out that Rusheng is making use here of the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Answer (score 1):

How many numbers in that range *do not* share any prime factor with $360$? Clearly:
$$ \varphi(360) = \varphi(2^3\cdot 3^2\cdot 5) = 4\cdot 6\cdot 4 = 96 $$
hence there are $360-96=\color{red}{264}$ numbers that do the opposite.